# Get freespace of mapped network drive using Win32_MappedLogicalDisk

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am trying to create logic to find free space on both a local drive and a UNC path mapped to a drive.

The logic to find free space on a local drive works fine. As for UNC path mapped drives, I have read that `Win32_LogicalDisk` doesn't reliably do this for mapped drives, so have been trying to get `Win32_MappedLogicalDisk` to work with either `.caption` and I have seen in one example code, and `.DeviceID` (the latter because after looking up the former it seems to be read-only).

However even after verifying that the logic is supplying `Win32_MappedLogicalDisk.DeviceID='E:'` to `objWMI.get(s)`, I am getting `Invalid object path / 8004103A / SWbemServicesEx` errors.

I don't often see the form `objWMI.get` in examples (usually it is the longer `GetObject("winmgmts:"...` and `...execquery` variety), so not sure if using the short of the two is causing the problem.

*As an aside:* If anyone could elaborate as to what the differences between `getobject(""winmgmts:"` and `objWMI.get...` are, or point me to reading material on the subject, that would be great. Like the shorter version but figure this is probably limited use.

Find below the logic as it is now:

```
TempDrive = ""

SkipSpaceCheck = false

s = wscript.scriptfullname

if left(s, 2) = "\\" then

  for i = 69 to 90

     ss = chr(i) & ":"

     if not objFSO.driveexists(ss) then

        TempDrive = ss

        exit for

     end if

  next

  if TempDrive <> "" then

     objNetwork.mapnetworkdrive TempDrive, left(s, instrrev(s, "\") - 1)

     s = "Win32_MappedLogicalDisk.DeviceID='" & TempDrive & "'"

  else

     SkipSpaceCheck = true

  end if

else

  s = objFSO.getfile(s).drive

  s = "Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" & s & "'"

end if

if not SkipSpaceCheck then

   wscript.echo s

   set objLDisk = objWMI.get(s)

   if cdbl(objLDisk.freespace) < cdbl(MinStorageSpace) then

      strConfirm = msgbox("Drive " & s & " has ONLY " & round(objLDisk.freespace / 1048576, 1) & "MB space free. Continue?", 36, "Test")

      if strConfirm = 7 then wscript.quit

    end if

   if TempDrive <> "" then objNetwork.removenetworkdrive Tempdrive

else

   wscript.echo "Space check skipped on account of no spare drive letters available to map UNC script running directory to, to obtain free space" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Click OK to proceed"

end if
```